# AND two binary strings

Tags: c++

I have to write a function in c++ where input are 2 binary strings and output has to be one string which is AND bitwise of two strings which are input. Also the output has to have a length of a shorter of the two inputs.

For example 
if input is:  "0b000000", "0b000000"
Output is: "0b000000"

if input is:  "0b10101010", "0b11111111"
Output is: "0b10101010"

if input is:  "0b10", "0b11111111"
Output is: "0b10"

if input is:  "0b10101110", "0b101"
Output is: "0b100"

Here is my code:

```
string binaryAND(const string &number1, const string &number2) {

    string first_sol = "";
    string sol = "0b";
    if (number1.length() < number2.length()) {

        string number11 = "";
        string number22 = "";

        for (int i = 2; i < number1.size(); i++){
            number11 += number1[i];
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < number2.size(); i++){
            number22 += number2[i];
        }


        int num1_z = stoi(number11, nullptr, 2);
        int num2_z = stoi(number22, nullptr, 2);

        int sol_int = (num1_z & num2_z);

        int i = number11.size();

        while (i > -1){
            first_sol = to_string(sol_int % 2) + first_sol;
            sol_int /= 2;
            i--;
        }

        sol += first_sol;
        return sol;
    }


    if (number1.length() >= number2.length()){
        string number11 = "";
        string number22 = "";

        for (int i = 2; i < number1.size(); i++){
            number11 += number1[i];
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < number2.size(); i++){
            number22 += number2[i];
        }


        int num1_z = stoi(number11, nullptr, 2);
        int num2_z = stoi(number22, nullptr, 2);

        int sol_int = (num1_z & num2_z);


        int i = number22.size();
        while (i > -1){

            first_sol = to_string(sol_int % 2) + first_sol;
            sol_int /= 2;
            i--;
        }
        sol += first_sol;
        return sol;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
But it does not work. The output behind "0b" has one more 0 than it should have.

For example output shoud be: "0b000000"
but it is: "0b0000000"

shoud be: "0b10101010"
but it is: "0b010101010"

shoud be: "0b100"
but it is: "0b0100"

I do not know how to correct the code. Any ideas, please?

Comment: `sol + first_sol;` doesn't change `sol`. Do you mean `sol += first_sol;`?

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica  Oh, yeah! You are right!  I didn't see that mistake. Thank you! But now the output is still a bit different than how it should be. I am gonna edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an expression without effect:

```
sol + first_sol;
```

You probably meant to use

```
sol += first_sol;
```

In the edited version you are probably still iterating too often: use

```
while (i > 0)
```

I’d personally recommend a *much* simpler approach:

```
std::string result;
auto min = std::min(number1.size(), number2.size());
std::transform(number1.begin(), number1.begin() + min,
               number2.begin(),
               std::back_inserter(result),
               [](char a, char b){
                   return a == 'b'? 'b': "01"[a == '1' && b == '1'];
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in addition to @DietmarKuhl's nice answer, note the "lesson" he is trying to teach you: There is a lot of functionality you can achieve by simply using standard library algorithms, like `std::transform` - so it's important to take some time and study them.

Also, even if you just wanted to implement your own solution - you have a couple of loops which are really just the same as calling `std::copy_n()`; and so on.

Finally - a somewhat different short-solution, which IMHO adheres better to the ["principle of least astonishment"](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment):

```
std::string result {"0b"};
auto min = std::min(number1.size(), number2.size());
std::transform(
    number1.begin() + 2, 
    number1.begin() + min,
    number2.begin() + 2,
    std::back_inserter(result),
    [](char a, char b){ return ((a == '1') and (b == '1')) ? '1' : '0'; }
);
```

Comment: Since '0' = 0x30 and '1' = 0x31 it is possible to apply the real binary AND(&) on characters, like this: [](char a, char b) { return a & b; }

Comment: @jenkas: That might work, but it does not easily occur to people. Also, if someone were to adapt this code to some other character set, this would no longer be the case and whoever adapts might miss this fact. Now, it's true that if you wanted to maximize performance you would do that - but then, you wouldn't be using an `std::string` result; and you would process more than a single character at a time etc.